# How to get Pyramid renderred array in Javascript of pug template

Tags: pug, pyramid, pypugjs

So I have a Pyramid view

```py
@view_config(route_name='myview', renderer='myview.pug')
    def myview(self):
        myarray = [1, 2, "abc"]
        return {
            'myarray': myarray,
        }
```

I want to parse `myarray` variable into Javascript array in `myview.pug` but can't, seems Pyramid escape all double quotes into `&#39;`

```
script.
    let myArray = #{myarray};
```

=> Unexpected token '&'

or

```
script.
    let myArray = '#{myarray}';
```

=> `[1, 2, &#39;abc&#39;]`

Comment: try return JSON.stringify and script let myArray = JSON.parse

Comment: thanks, it worked, I wonder if we have special filter or something without the need to json.dumps(myarray) @MaiTruong